# How can I repeat rows in a Table based on matching condition from another Table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have two Tables below A&B. I want to transform Table A into Table C by duplicating rows from Table A, filling in the missing dates from Table B's date column which will result in equal number of rows for each id.

TABLE A

| id | Dates | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/09/2010 | 4 |
| 1 | 01/03/2011 | 3 |
| 2 | 01/12/2011 | 3 |
| 3 | 01/03/2011 | 1 |
| 3 | 01/06/2011 | 1 |
| 3 | 01/09/2011 | 1 |

TABLE B

| Dates |
| --- |
| 01/09/2010 |
| 01/12/2010 |
| 01/03/2011 |
| 01/06/2011 |
| 01/09/2011 |

TABLE C

| id | Dates | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/09/2010 | 4 |
| 1 | 01/12/2010 | null |
| 1 | 01/03/2011 | 3 |
| 1 | 01/06/2011 | null |
| 1 | 01/09/2011 | null |
| 2 | 01/09/2010 | null |
| 2 | 01/12/2010 | null |
| 2 | 01/03/2011 | 3 |
| 2 | 01/06/2011 | null |
| 2 | 01/09/2011 | null |
| 3 | 01/09/2010 | null |
| 3 | 01/12/2010 | null |
| 3 | 01/03/2011 | 1 |
| 3 | 01/06/2011 | 1 |
| 3 | 01/09/2011 | 1 |

Comment: Please don't paste pictures, Please post your data as copiable text. Thanks

Comment: This may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/merge-queries-full-outer

Comment: @Anonymous this was not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery this generates all combos of dates and id, then merges in existing data

```
let  Source = Table.Distinct(Table.SelectColumns(TableA,{"id"})),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Dates", each List.Distinct(TableA[Dates]&TableB[Dates])),
#"Expanded Dates" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Dates"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Dates", {"id", "Dates"}, TableA, {"id", "Dates"}, "TableA", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded TableA" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "TableA", {"Amount"}, {"Amount"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded TableA",{{"Dates", type date}})
in #"Changed Type"
```

[image]

Comment: Good bit of lateral thinking - nice work.

Comment: Did this answer your question